# How to communicate Raspberry Pi 3 with Arduino via ISP with C#?

Tags: c#

Currently need use the Xamarin as IDE.
I need communicate a raspberry as master with a Arduino Pro mini as slave using C#. 
I dont know how to call/set the MISO and the MOSI. I believe that have a library to be used as system.IO, but I really dont know and saw anything using C#.
Can anyone help me?

Thx.